# convert date format in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Hi i have some categories in Highchart something like:

```
 Categories:["2015-10-31", "2015-11-04", "2015-11-12", "2015-11-03", "2015-11-11", "2015-11-02", "2015-11-01", "2015-11-13"]
```

its displaying on x axis but i want to change date format like this:

**oct 31 nov 4 nov 12 nov 3,nov 11** some thing like this format

How can i achieve like this
if any one can help me please help i am unable to get solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formatter method: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter

Example:

```js
$(function () {
    var months = [
        'Jan', 
        'Feb', 
        'Mar', 
        'Apr', 
        'May', 
        'Jun', 
        'Jul', 
        'Aug', 
        'Sep',
        'Oct',
        'Nov',
        'Dec'
    ];
    $('#container').highcharts({

        title: {
            text: 'Example'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ["2015-10-31", "2015-11-04", "2015-11-12"],

            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    var date = new Date(this.value);
                    return months[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getDate();
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [1, 2, 3]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
"xAxis": {
                  "type": "datetime",
                      "labels": {
                      "format": "{value:%b %d}"
                  },
                  categories:["2015-10-31", "2015-11-04", "2015-11-12", "2015-11-03", "2015-11-11", "2015-11-02", "2015-11-01", "2015-11-13"]

         };
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat

Comment: where will place ctrgories?

Comment: Where were you putting it earlier?

Comment: If it solves you problem kindly considering voting up and marking it as correct answer.